# Have keyevent listener method constantly checking input

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I wrote this method:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
            if (isEncryption){
                ctaTarget.setText(codModule.kodiere(this.getText()));
            } else {
                ctaTarget.setText(codModule.dekodiere(this.getText()));
            }
        } else {
            append(""+e.getKeyChar());
        }
    }
```

It is the method of a class extending JTextArea (yes, I know extending is suboptimal but I won't need anything else for the intended application, at least not to my knowledge).
It is supposed to check every character being entered into the JTextArea and send the message (the settext part) if the key being pressed is the right arrow.
Now if I add an object of the class I created to my GUI nothing happens.
Am I forgetting something I don't know about?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The official Java Tutorials are always a good resource. In this case, I would recommend the [KeyListener tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) and related tutorials.

Comment: Could you please include all the necessary information to answer this question? Other visitors might be confused as they won't necessarily read the comments beneath my answer. Generally, questions should be [SSCCEs](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have correctly implemented the `KeyListener` interface, though apparently you did not add it as such.

Your class still doesn't know anything about your implementation *until* you added it using `Component.addKeyListener()`, i.e. in its constructor like this:

```java
this.addKeyListener(this);
```

With this, we tell it to use its own implementation of `KeyListener`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer!
I will try it out and see if it works. It would seem I actually did not implement that interface. I just found a similar structured code online and used it but changed it so that it would serve my purpose. 
I implemented the interface now but I am being asked to also implement the "keyTyped" method. Is that really necessary?  What are the differences between the two?

Comment: Implementing an interface means implementing all of its declared methods. Even though you don't need the other methods of `KeyListener`, they still need to be implemented. Though the implementation may very well be empty (`public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}`).

Comment: Telling Java that your class implements an interface is done via the `implements` keyword. Only declaring methods of similar signatures doesn't mean that your class implements an interface to Java, _until_ you have used `implements`.

Comment: That did it, thanks! It works as intended now.